# Endpoint or route inaccurate? (axios call works in code but not on postman)

Tags: node.js, express, axios

After following a tutorial for a MERN login system using a REST api, I've been trying to write my own patch method. However it's not working correctly so I've been trying to understand the already written routes and methods from the tutorial. **When I login/register, axios will post to the specific endpoint and will log in fine but when I try to test it on Postman it's not working.** Here's an example:

```
const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const loginUser = {email, password};
            const loginResponse = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/login", loginUser);
            setUserData({
                token: loginResponse.data.token,
                user: loginResponse.data.user
            });
            localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginResponse.data.token);
            history.push("/dashboard");
        } catch(err) {
            err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg)
        }
        
    };
```

with the corresponding route:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // validate
    if (!email || !password)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Not all fields have been entered." });

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "No account with this email has been registered." });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials." });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    console.log("token",token);
    res.json({
      token,
      user: {
        id: user._id,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        favPokemon: user.favPokemon,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

and this will work fine. However with the following Postman request,
[image]

then it responds with the error message created. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending email and password fields as 'Params' (Query Params) instead as 'Body', as seen in the screenshot

POST http://localhost:5000/users/login

Body: application/json (raw)

{
"email": "test@test.com",
"password": "test123"
}